# iOS Binary not encrypted Test-flight Build

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, encryption, ipa

Hey guys recently our app has given for Penetrating testing to check the security vulnerabilities. We have distributed our app from **Test-Flight** using **AppStore Distribution profile** to Security team and they have come back with a security issue saying **iOS App Binary is not encrypted.**

As per my knowledge the binary encryption is part of the **App Store release process**. It does not apply to ad-hoc/testing apps as it would get in the way of debugging.

Does the app which released from Test-Flight for External and internal testers is binary encrypted.? If not, incase if i'm planning to release the same app using Enterprise distribution how do i make sure my binary is encrypted. Should i implement Obsfucation.

Kindly provide your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, any updates on if you were able to solve this? got the same comment on our pen test report.

Comment: I believe the encryption will happen only when the app is released from Appstore as per the comment in apple developers forum https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/77886

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. I got the ipa from AppStore and we ran the pen test again. The encrypted status was now true. Thanks for the reply